# R - Building a histogram with data in intervals (from survey)

Tags: r

I'm currently analysing some data I've retrieved from a survey and I want to create a histogram with it.

The problem is that the data is in pairs of range-absolute frequency, something like with different ranges:

[image: example]

Since the intervals are not the same, how can I generate the histogram in R?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want a bar chart instead of a histogram. Here's an [article](https://www.forbes.com/sites/naomirobbins/2012/01/04/a-histogram-is-not-a-bar-chart/#121a36436d77) that explains the difference nicely.

For a barchart with the data you provided in the format you've indicated you could do something like this:

```
my_data <- data.frame(range = c('[0-2]','[2-5]','[5-9]'),
                      abs_frequency = c(2,10,5))

library(ggplot2)
plot <- ggplot(data = my_data, aes(x = range, y = abs_frequency))
plot +
  geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

Comment: Thank you very much! 
This did exactly what I was looking for! :)

Comment: Also, one little tip: I managed to make it look more like a histogram by reducing the space between bars with `width=0.985` in `aes(x = range, y = abs_frequency, width=0.985)`.

1 can be used in order to remove all the space between bars.